# Can't import my own .py modules in python when run from apache uwsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, uwsgi, importerror

I wanted to create my own API so I settled down with apache2, uwsgi, flask and python. 
I followed these instruction [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

I changed modules:

- libapache2-mod-wsgi -> libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
- python-dev -> python3-dev
- python-pip -> python3-pip

I changed commands:

- sudo virtualenv whitedust -> sudo virtualenv -p python3.6 whitedust
- source envname/bin/activate -> source whitedust/bin/activate

At this point I continue the guide normally and got the system working.
But then when I tried to add my own file it gave an error

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured

Apache error.log:

```
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838360 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961] mod_wsgi (pid=24654): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838397 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961] mod_wsgi (pid=24654): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838553 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838572 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838574 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838577 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838579 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961]     import utils
[Wed Jun 27 15:12:53.838587 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 24654:tid 140042661635840] [remote 192.168.1.6:38961] ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Here's the apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ProxyPass /api !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When the system was working I did check where the __init__:py files sees it self

Path: /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp

This all works when run outside of apache in python or virtual environment

I also tried to install modules through pip and they did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following lines before the imports in your wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/directory/containing/utils")
```

Comment: nwm I got the dependencies